# How do i access the same variable in multiple classes? (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to modify a variable in one class and iT to be accessed in another class in my program. How do i do this? and if there is, will the variable be updated in one class when i change it in another.

Comment: static public variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the dependency injection pattern, there are some libraries to help you if you have a big project but if you just want to do something small you can hand craft it.

Create a class that will contain the shared variable

```
class SharedClass{
  public int commonVar{get;set;} //not threadsafe
}
```

Every class that needs to have access to it it must get a reference to it through constructor.

```
class ConsumerOne{
   SharedClass shared; 
   public ConsumerOne(SharedClass shared)
   { 
      this.shared = shared;
   }
   public IncreaseThat(){ 
      shared.commonVar++;
   }
}
```

```
class ConsumerTwo{
   SharedClass shared; 
   public ConsumerTwo(SharedClass shared)
   { 
      this.shared = shared;
   }
   public DecreaseThat(){ 
      shared.commonVar--;
   }
}
```

And at your Program main you make the binding.

```
main(){
   var shared = new SharedClass();
   var one = new ConsumerOne(shared);
   var two = new ConsumerTwo(shared);

   one.IncreaseThat();
   Console.WriteLine(shared.commonVar);
   two.DecreaseThat();
   Console.WriteLine(shared.commonVar);
}
```

That way you can tell what your classes are using and you will skip global variables.

Comment: In simple cases one could declare SharedClass as static and not need to pass the reference around.

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli Its much better practice to pass every dependency in the constructor of the class. That way you can see what are the class dependencies without having to scan all the code and you can migrate much easier to a multi-user multi-thread environment. When I created Chordastic, a single user desktop app, i used this approach and rather it needed much more plumbing, it was a breeze to migrate it to the web. The things i thought they should be Static in the desktop were used as normal objects per session in the web.

Comment: I specified “simple” for this reason, while I agree with you on expandable foundations being good in the long run, they are more complex. For experiments and while learning the language, I wanted to point out a static class is easier to manage and get things to a working state

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli Sure, its easier. It's already included in the answer above mine. I just provide a better way not so solve the specific problem he encounter but a way to become a better developer and implement maintainable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution: define it as `public static` in `Program` class. Then access it from any class with `Program.var_name`.